# updating DOM inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have created a directive that uses template having `ng-repeat='row in rows'`. I am using a button to insert one row at a time with fields and using `link` function to update DOM inside `ng-repeat` with div like:

```
var div = '<div>' +
  '<input type="text" ng-model="row.name">' +
'</div>';
var e = $compile(div)(scope);
jQuery('#myDiv').replaceWith(e);
```

The problem is I can't use the `row` object of `ng-repeat` due to which it doesn't update the `name`. Is there any way to compile with current `row` object of `rows`?

I am actually using database to show data in `ng-repeat` and for certain fields I have to use `textarea` and for others have to use `text` box, which I don't think is possible inside template. So, I am using `link` function inside directive and update DOM.

Comment: Where does this code reside? Try showing a more complete example. Also, why aren't you just adding data and letting `ng-repeat` handle rendering?

Comment: I am actually using database to show data in ng-repeat and for certain fields I have to use textarea and for others have to use text box, which I don't think is possible inside template. So, I am using link function inside directive and update DOM.

Comment: Have a look at `angular formly`

Comment: @entre that's completely a different approach and it's useful only when you have single form on the page. In my case, I have to use database table rows and display them in output with different fields. The output will also be in multiple rows.

Comment: I'm still not sure you actually need this alternative approach, to my mind you could just use `ng-repeat` like Sacho said and select which widget to use for each row using `ng-if`.